# Mongo intermittently throws "Duplicate Key" error, despite force deleted key?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

In Typescript/NodeJS, inserting a document into MongoDB intermittently gives me a `E11000 duplicate key error`.

I have a global object that maintains the application state. Any time this state changes, I want to log it into MongoDB as a new entry with a new timestamp. This only happens every few seconds.

The state object does not inherently have an "_id" field, but reading or inserting it into the MongoDB automatically assigns an _id field, and I cannot find a way to remove it at all.

Here is my code to insert the state (named pools) into Mongo- I explicitly delete the ID field:

```
export async function updatePoolState(pools: State): Promise<boolean> {
  //@ts-ignore
  delete pools["_id"]
  //@ts-ignore
  console.log(`Insert with ID ${pools["_id"]}`)
  const success = (await poolDb.insertOne(pools)).acknowledged;
  return success;
}
```

Note that //@ts-ignore is REQUIRED for this to compile, because the State object doesn't actually maintain an ID.

Consistently at startup, and intermittently during normal runtime, the following statements are printed:

```
Insert with ID undefined

MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: database.pools index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('646eb8abff0f97eb6481f400') }
```

How in the world does he object have a duplicate "_id" of '646...', when it's clearly undefined? Why does this only happen sometimes? How can I prevent it? Thanks.

Comment: Well this is interesting and maybe helpful? `> ObjectId('646eb8abff0f97eb6481f400').getTimestamp()
ISODate("2023-05-25T01:23:55.000Z")`

Comment: That is actually very helpful! I didn't know my library generates a key based off the timestamp. At startup, I did try to insert two documents within a second. That must have been the issue. I'll consider this solved. If you post an answer with a little more detail, I will accept it.